# Get Max Date Without Grouping By - Complex Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Here's my starting query that works great.

QUESTION:
I want to add into the select something that will return MAX (c.Date) as [LastCostDate] as part of the results.  But obviously, just adding that itself requires that I GROUP BY, but I don't want to.  Is there another way that I can accomplish this?

```
SELECT
o.WorkOrder as [Work Order], o.ServiceSite as [Site], o.Description as [Description], o.LeadTechnician as [PM], r.Name as [PM Name], r.RevEmail as [PM Email], o.Notes as [Notes]
FROM
    SMWorkOrder o
    LEFT JOIN SMWorkCompleted c
            ON o.WorkOrder = c.WorkOrder
            AND c.Date >= DATEADD(WEEK,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND c.Date <= GETDATE()
            AND c.SMCo = 1
      LEFT JOIN HQRV r
            ON o.LeadTechnician = r.Reviewer
      LEFT JOIN SMInvoiceList l
            ON o.SMCo = l.SMCo
            AND o.WorkOrder = l.WorkOrder
WHERE
    c.WorkOrder is NULL
    AND o.SMCo = 1 AND o.WOStatus not in (1,2)
      AND o.EnteredDateTime <= DATEADD(WEEK,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Comment: `MAX (c.Date)` for?

Comment: It might help if you show sample data and output.

Comment: Write another subquery with your max date grouping and join it in.

Comment: Why you wouldn't want to add a group by?

Comment: It is a complex query because you have not completely defined what your "max ..." value represents. Look at the join to SMWorkCompleted (c). Do you need to include the same conditions in your "max" logic? Think carefully - you use a left join to that table, so you expect that the join will not always include a matching row. And your where clause will **GUARANTEE** that nothing matches.

Answer (score 2):

`MAX (c.Date) OVER( ... )` will return max c.date for condition in `OVER` (can be empty)